# Precision Voltage Reference 0.675V +- 0.005

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-reference, precision

Is it possible and reasonable to make a voltage reference that outputs 0.675V +- 0.005 over an input of 6 to 40 volts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

.675V +/- 0.005V is +/- 0.7%.

Digikey lists a lot of voltage references at 0.5% or better regulation.

Once you choose a reference, you can adapt the input voltage (if necessary) with a preregulator, and you can adapt the output voltage (if necessary) with a resistor divider.

Comment: That 0.5% is usually also *initial* accuracy. They're generally much better with regard to drift. You would just need to trim the output voltage once, when you first assemble the system.

Comment: Someone should explain why accurate references are less favored over ones with controlled drift/tempco. Connor Wolf's comment deserves a separate answer

Comment: I would like to see @ConnorWolf expand into a full answer as well.  Trims have their own costs and drawbacks.  If a spec can be fulfilled with fixed components of reasonable cost, that makes a better design.

Comment: @markrages - I certainly wouldn't argue that something you can do that doesn't involve manual trimming is a lot nicer from the assembly process. However, it tends to be more expensive.As usual, it's a matter of where your priorities are (accurate, easy, cheap - pick any two).